# Derivatives of Probability Distributions

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives

Today in one of my textbooks, I saw the following relationship provided about multivariate Probability Distribution Functions (e.g. $f(y, \theta)$) :

$$\frac{\partial f(y,u|\theta)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f(y|\theta)}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial f(u|y, \theta)}{\partial \theta}$$

**My Question:** I am trying to understand - what laws of derivative calculus and probability can be used to understand why this mathematical relationship is true?

Here is what I did so far using the Laws of Conditional Probability:

Left Hand Side:

$$f(y , u| \theta) = \frac{f(y, u, \theta)}{f(\theta)}$$

Right Hand Side:

$$f(y | \theta) \cdot f(u | y, \theta) = \frac{f(y, \theta)}{f(\theta)} \cdot \frac{f(u , y, \theta)}{f(y, \theta)} = \frac{f(u, y, \theta)}{f(\theta)}$$

So you can show that the Left Hand Side equals to the Right Hand Side.

But I do not know how to continue from here. Can someone please show me what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you are dealing with probability distribution function? I guess that your relation holds if $f$ is the logarithm of some p.d.f.

Comment: @night_owl:  thank you for your reply! do you think you can please show me how to proceed?

Comment: I wrote some proof for my argument! Can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from comment, I will assume $f$ is logarithm of probability (log-pdf) density of $p$.

As you noted, by *Laws of Conditional Probability*, we have:
$$
p(y,u|\theta) = p(y|\theta)\cdot p(y|u,\theta)\,.
$$

By applying logarithm on both side, we get:
\begin{align}
f(y,u|\theta) &= \log{p(y,u|\theta)}= \log{\big(p(y|\theta)\cdot p(y|u,\theta)\big)} \\
&=\log{p(y|\theta)} + \log{p(y|u,\theta)}\\
&=f(y|\theta) +  f(y|u,\theta)\,.
\end{align}

By applying derivative with $\theta$ on both side, we finally have:

$$
\frac{\partial f(y,u|\theta)}{\partial\theta}= \frac{\partial f(y|\theta)}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial f(y|u,\theta)}{\partial\theta}\,.
$$

Comment: looks great to me! thank you so much!

Comment: do you have any ideas about this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787116/finding-the-name-of-this-algebra-identity