# Finding the name of this algebra identity

Tags: linear-algebra

I found the algebra identity in my math textbook:

\begin{equation}
\text{If } K'X = 0 \text{ for } K \text{ of full column rank and } H \text{ is positive definite, then:}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
K(K'HK)'K' = H^{-1} - H^{-1}X (X'H^{-1}X)^{-1} X'H^{-1} = P
\end{equation}

**My Question:** I am trying to understand if this algebra identity has a special name and also understand why it is true.

After doing some digging on the internet, I found something which might be applicable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity:

\begin{equation}
(A + UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}
\end{equation}

I think if certain substitutions are made, such as (for example):

\begin{align*}
A & = H, \\
U & = H^{-\frac{1}{2}}X, \\
C & = I, \\
V & = H^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}

We might be able to recreate the above identity. But I am still not sure why $H$ necessarily needs to be full column rank and positive definitive for this identity to be true.

**Can someone please help me understands why this identity is true (i.e. how to prove it) and why the full rank/positive definite property is required?**

Thanks!

- PS: Why is this identity and the Woodbury identity important? Does it have any special applications/use cases in the real world?

Comment: What does apostrophe stand for?